# How to assign stringid (dynamic) using strings.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

how would i assign the stringid dynamic, i have created number of string field in the strings.xml file.

strings.xml

```
<string name="read_more_0">defautl message</string> 
<string name="read_more_1">first messages.</string> 
<string name="read_more_2">second messages.</string> 
<string name="read_more_3">third messages.</string>
```

simple activity:

```
 public class dynamic_Activity extends Activity {
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           setContentView(R.layout.dynamic_layout_01);

          txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);  

          //getting position value from the previous activity
          int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", default_value); 

          if (position > 0)
          {  
          String _format = "read_more_" + String.valueOf(position);
          txtDisplay.setText(R.string._format); // how to assign the string id?

          } else {
          txtDisplay.setText(R.string.read_more_0); //by default
          }  
       }
    }
```

layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/dynamic_0" 
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, I think you should look into using a [string array resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray).

Comment: +1 simply because I forgot about string arrays in my post. It is definitely another way to do it.

Comment: i tried the sample `<string-array` the link you posted and it works fine but when i try to paste my real text which is a long text and then does not work and when i click on the link it loads the same activity without going to a different activity and its strange... and i put it back the sample data and it works fine.. any thoughts?

Comment: You probably have some encoding/escaping issue. The most common character for me is the apostrophe. Make sure that you backslash-escape those.

Comment: yep i see that i have ', " . ( )' how do i deal with that

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything for .() but for ' and ", you want to backslash escape them: \' and \"

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do this:

1) Declare a map or switch statement in your class that links the positions to the resource ids. This will give better performance.

2) If you **must** get a resource from a dynamic string you can use the [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method. Note that the performance isn't great.

```
Resources resources = getResources();
int id = resources.getIdentifier("read_more_" + String.valueOf(position), "string", getPackageName());
String str = resources.getString(id);
```

Comment: what i will do with str assign it to txtDisplay?

Comment: wow... i did not know about the degrade of performance if i go with option #2

Comment: look at this link and the author thinks if he goes without case statement the performane boost, check this out: http://www.justin.my/2011/12/dynamic-string-using-string-xml-in-android/

Comment: @AbuHamzah Yes, you assign the String to txtDisplay

Comment: the performance is a big deal for me, so can you tell me more about option #1 vs #2 and you have said the perofmance will be slow if i go with #2

Comment: @AbuHamzah I haven't tested the performance myself. Unless you are dealing with a significant amount of elements (I would say at least 20-30), I would guess the second way would probably work fine.

Comment: @AbuHamzah Again, I don't know if it will make a significant difference in your app. Considering that it is a small amount of code it wouldn't be hard for you to test it out.

Comment: well... the reason i asked you because you have mentiond in your post that `performance isn't great` soi just wanted to know about the perofrmance

Comment: @AbuHamzah If you follow my link for the getIdentifier function, it mentions in the docs that use of this function is discouraged because it is more efficient to retrieve resources by the identifier instead of using this method.

Answer (score 0):

You cant. Do

```
switch (position) {
case 0: txtDisplay.setText(R.string.read_more_0); break;
case 1: txtDisplay.setText(R.string.read_more_1); break;
// and so forth...
}
```